# Ввод дробных чисел через input

Tags: javascript, html, input

Такая проблема: есть input типа "text":

```
<input id="WPVG" type="text" name="workpay">
```

В него вводятся дробные числа (например, 1.1), но когда я пытаюсь производить применить полученное значение в каком-либо условии, с использованием дробных значений, система выбирает лишь два возможных варианта: 0 и 1, а все остальные дробные варианты просто игнорирует. При этом нет никаких ошибок, из-за чего я не могу понять, что не так.

```
let WorkPayVG = 0; 
WorkPayVG = Number(document.querySelector('[name="workpay"]').value);
if (WorkPayVG == 0) {
     document.getElementById('RVG03').style.display = 'inline';
     document.getElementById('RVG03').style.color = 'red';
     document.getElementById('RVG03').innerHTML = 'Warning! Your people are unhappy that you don\'t pay them! Settle this issue quickly or it may lead to an uprising and loss of people!';
   } else if (0 < WorkPayVG <= 0.25) {
     document.getElementById('RVG03').style.display = 'inline';
     document.getElementById('RVG03').style.color = 'red';
     document.getElementById('RVG03').innerHTML = 'Warning! Your people are unhappy that you pay them too little for their work! Please resolve this issue quickly or it may lead to people fleeing!'
   } else if (0.25 < WorkPayVG <= 0.5) {
     document.getElementById('RVG03').style.display = 'inline';
     document.getElementById('RVG03').style.color = 'red';
     document.getElementById('RVG03').innerHTML = 'Warning! You pay your people too little! If you don\'t take action, they will begin to starve!';
   } else if (0.5 < WorkPayVG <= 0.75) {
     document.getElementById('RVG03').style.display = 'inline';
     document.getElementById('RVG03').style.color = 'red';
     document.getElementById('RVG03').innerHTML = 'Warning! Your people\'s income is barely enough to make ends meet!';
   } else if (0.75 < WorkPayVG <= 1) {
     document.getElementById('RVG03').style.display = 'inline';
     document.getElementById('RVG03').style.color = 'green';
     document.getElementById('RVG03').innerHTML = 'Your people are fed and clothed, what else is needed for happiness?'
     console.log('WorkPayVG 0.75-1:', WorkPayVG);
   } else if (WorkPayVG > 1) {
     document.getElementById('RVG03').style.display = 'inline';
     document.getElementById('RVG03').style.color = 'green';
     document.getElementById('RVG03').innerHTML = 'Your people are happy about your generosity, which translates into increased efficiency at work.';
     console.log('WorkPayVG >1:', WorkPayVG);
   }
```

Помогите понять, что не так? Почему система не видит дробных чисел?
Подозреваю, что прблема в типе данных, но как указать системе, что нужно учитывать дробную часть, не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let WorkPayVG = 0;
    WorkPayVG = parseFloat(document.querySelector('[name="workpay"]').value);

    if (WorkPayVG == 0) {
        document.getElementById('RVG03').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('RVG03').style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('RVG03').innerHTML = 'Warning! Your people are unhappy that you don\'t pay them! Settle this issue quickly or it may lead to an uprising and loss of people!';
    } else if (WorkPayVG > 0 && WorkPayVG <= 0.25) {
        document.getElementById('RVG03').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('RVG03').style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('RVG03').innerHTML = 'Warning! Your people are unhappy that you pay them too little for their work! Please resolve this issue quickly or it may lead to people fleeing!';
    } else if (WorkPayVG > 0.25 && WorkPayVG <= 0.5) {
        document.getElementById('RVG03').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('RVG03').style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('RVG03').innerHTML = 'Warning! You pay your people too little! If you don\'t take action, they will begin to starve!';
    } else if (WorkPayVG > 0.5 && WorkPayVG <= 0.75) {
        document.getElementById('RVG03').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('RVG03').style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('RVG03').innerHTML = 'Warning! Your people\'s income is barely enough to make ends meet!';
    } else if (WorkPayVG > 0.75 && WorkPayVG <= 1) {
        document.getElementById('RVG03').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('RVG03').style.color = 'green';
        document.getElementById('RVG03').innerHTML = 'Your people are fed and clothed, what else is needed for happiness?';
        console.log('WorkPayVG 0.75-1:', WorkPayVG);
    } else if (WorkPayVG > 1) {
        document.getElementById('RVG03').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('RVG03').style.color = 'green';
        document.getElementById('RVG03').innerHTML = 'Your people are happy about your generosity, which translates into increased efficiency at work.';
        console.log('WorkPayVG > 1:', WorkPayVG);
    }
```

В JavaScript операторы сравнения не поддерживают сравнение диапазонов с использованием двух операторов (< и <=) в одном выражении. Вместо этого вы должны сравнивать каждое значение отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил вообще отказаться от множественных if-ов, сделав массив с граничными значениями с перебором в цикле. Это и нагляднее и компактнее.

```js
msgs = [[0, 'red', 'Warning! Your people are unhappy that you don\'t pay them! Settle this issue quickly or it may lead to an uprising and loss of people!'],
    [0.25, 'red', 'Warning! Your people are unhappy that you don\'t pay them! Settle this issue quickly or it may lead to an uprising and loss of people!'],
    [0.5, 'red', 'Warning! You pay your people too little! If you don\'t take action, they will begin to starve!'],
    [0.75, 'red', 'Warning! Your people\'s income is barely enough to make ends meet!'],
    [1, 'green', 'Your people are fed and clothed, what else is needed for happiness?'],
    [Infinity, 'green', 'Your people are happy about your generosity, which translates into increased efficiency at work.']]

let WorkPayVG = prompt('Введите WorkPayVG [0+]: ').replace(',','.');
for (let i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
    if (WorkPayVG <= msgs[i][0]) {
        console.info(`WorkPayVG задан ${WorkPayVG}, это попадает в ячейку от (${i > 0 ? msgs[i - 1][0] : -Infinity} < ${WorkPayVG} <= ${msgs[i][0]}]`)
        console.log(`document.getElementById('RVG03').style.display = 'inline';
document.getElementById('RVG03').style.color = '${msgs[i][1]}';
document.getElementById('RVG03').innerHTML = '${msgs[i][2]}';`)
        break;
    }
}
```